# Power ESP01 in forest

Tags: power, wifi

I want to do WiFi GeoChaching box. I'll use cheap ESP01, but problem is it will work in forest 24/7 in cycle of 1 min of work 5 in deep sleep and waiting for those who will find that.
How I can get power?

Comment: Either solar, or a very large battery. Or change the batteries every week. But I don't think Wifi is the best idea for this. I'd go with a Bluetooth Low Energy solution.

Comment: is there any cheap "board" like ESP01 with BT 4.0 and how big area i can cover? 
Any idea what i can do in dark places like abonded tunels etc?

Comment: Why not just play Pokemon Go like the rest of the universe?

Comment: The BBC MicroBit might be a viable option - built in BLE.

Comment: What is your energy budget (how much energy - milliWatt Hours, or average current at what voltage - will be needed during the one minute on-time)? And how often are you willing to change its battery pack?

Answer (score 1):

I think that in this case you will need multiple solutions for generating the power.

1. You need to know how much power you need.  This depends on you solution, I can't help there.
2. You need a backup battery, ideally one that doesn't mind constant trickle charge and deep discharge.  Sealed lead acid are probably the best.
3. Your battery must have enough power over a long enough time.
4. You need a power generator, wind, solar, water, chemical. And they should all have a common interface so you GeoCache is modular, so the GeoCaches can be plugged into any of the power sources, maybe even more than one source.

The problem with the power source is it is going to be a visual clue to where the cache is, probably also an audio clue.
The battery, if SLA, is going to be a great big lump that could be dangerous if damaged.
The caches are not going to be cheap, just because of the power source and battery, so I hope you have deep pockets.

Rather than looking for a ESP01+BT4 module look for any microprocessor with BT built in, it maybe a better way to go.

Comment: Tell me about that chemical generator pleas @Matt

Comment: Petrol, coal, nuclear which are probably not very practical in this situation.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_generation